# Cannot clone a repository in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

The VSCode step `git clone` isn't working.
I created a repository, then I uploaded files to it and try to clone it.

[image: error]

**Git log**

```
**[2022-03-12T18:20:41.605Z]** > git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git d:\projects\python\repo--progress [126ms]

**[2022-03-12T18:20:41.605Z]** Cloning into 'd:\projects\python\repo'...
```

Comment: Link on this repository does not exist I think there is a problem.

Comment: No, I typed this link for example. This repository exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if the same clone would work from command lien outside of VSCode.

An issue like [`microsoft/vscode` issue 58910](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58910) illustrates possible causes, like a [VMware Carbon Black](https://community.carbonblack.com/) product or other Windows updates.

But first, make sure you have the latest VSCode and [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).